# Using ArcObjects to open or access shapefile?

Tags: arcobjects

I am writing a program with a dialog box that when they click on the map button a shapefile will open. I wrote a program that opened a map document is it the same language as that is. Which is the following :

```
Dim pDoc As IDocument
Dim pApp As IApplication
Set pDoc = New MxDocument
Set pApp = pDoc.Parent
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a shapefile from a dialog box you can [find instructions/code here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//00490000005m000000).

You need to set your [ActiveView](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ActiveView_Property/000v00000113000000/) property in order to add anything to your map:

[image]

Comment: @MichelleCouden if that answers the question, mark it as so please.